# Merging XAML views?

Tags: xaml, windows-8, winrt-xaml, semantic-zoom

I come from a Android/iOS background and I am looking into building a landing page (using grids) that uses SemanticZoom and has 6 columns which are contained into a long horizontal scroll.

Each grid column will have different components and has a different width:

e.g.

- the 1st column will have a bunch of grid tiles and a stacked image with text
- the 2nd column a grid with documents thumbnails
- the 3rd coloumn a list of videos 
  etc.

I was wondering if there is a way through which XAML views could be merged (like in Android) or if anyone could suggest an efficient way through which I can construct this landing page?

Comment: Have looked into UserControls?

Comment: @MarkHall Checking it out now. Thanks.

Comment: I would stay away from user controls as they have issues with bindings. You should be able to manage your UI using templates, styles and resource dictionaries.

Comment: What issues with bindings?? Most apps use UserControls. A Page class is a UserControl. It's one the most commonly used controls in all XAML frameworks.

Comment: Not sure I understand this correctly, but here it goes: each column in the grid should inherit a UserControl. The UserControl for each column holds all the components specific to that column in a column "main" XAML layout?